# R convert dataframe to JSON

Tags: r, json, dataframe, rjson

I have a dataframe that I'd like to convert to json format:

my data frame called res1:

```
library(rjson)

structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), value = structure(1:5, .Label = c("server1", 
"server2", "server3", "server4", "server5"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("id", 
"value"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

when I do:

```
toJSON(res1)
```

I get this:

```
{"id":[1,2,3,4,5],"value":["server1","server2","server3","server4","server5"]}
```

I need this json output to be like this, any ideas?

```
[{"id":1,"value":"server1"},{"id":2,"value":"server2"},{"id":3,"value":"server3"},{"id":4,"value":"server4"},{"id":5,"value":"server5"}]
```

Comment: Why do you think you want it in that format? http://jsonlint.com/ says it's not valid.

Comment: @doctorlove, I've update the json format I need to see. Thank you.

Comment: Still not valid ;-) `Parse error on line 20:
... 5,        "value:"server5"}]
----------------------^
Expecting '}', ':', ',', ']'`

Comment: @doctorlove, I missed ", updated.

Comment: Better :-)  Do consider using http://jsonlint.com/ just to check in future.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

How about

```
library(rjson)
x <- toJSON(unname(split(res1, 1:nrow(res1))))
cat(x)
# [{"id":1,"value":"server1"},{"id":2,"value":"server2"},
# {"id":3,"value":"server3"},{"id":4,"value":"server4"},
# {"id":5,"value":"server5"}]
```

By using `split()` we are essentially breaking up the large data.frame into a separate data.frame for each row. And by removing the names from the resulting list, the `toJSON` function wraps the results in an array rather than a named object.

Comment: Thanks. And if we want split by row. `library(rjson);library(dplyr);res1<-data.frame(id= c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),server=c("server1", "server2", "server3", "server4", "server5"),y1=letters[1:5],y2=LETTERS[1:5])` with `res1$JsonList<-lapply ( (unname( split( (res1 %>% select_at (vars(starts_with("y")))), 1:nrow(res1)) ) ), function(x) rjson::toJSON(x) ) `  and with `res1 %>% select_at (vars(-starts_with("y")))`

Answer (score 65):

The [jsonlite](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/index.html) package exists to address exactly this problem: "A practical and consistent mapping between JSON data and R objects."

Its `toJSON` function provides this desired result with the default options:

```
library(jsonlite)
x <- toJSON(res1)
cat(x)

## [{"id":1,"value":"server1"},{"id":2,"value":"server2"},
## {"id":3,"value":"server3"},{"id":4,"value":"server4"},
## {"id":5,"value":"server5"}]
```

Comment: if you have the issue, that you have your values nested within an array, instead of a single value: use the option auto_unbox=TRUE in the toJSON function to unbox "value":["server1"] to "value": "server1". example command: toJSON(res1, pretty=TRUE, flatten=TRUE, auto_unbox=TRUE)

Answer (score 6):

Now you can easily just call `jsonlite::write_json()` directly on the dataframe.

Comment: `read_json` and `write_json` are designed to read/write from disk. `jsonlite::toJSON(res1)` is still the correct answer for this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `library(jsonify)`

```
jsonify::to_json( res1 )
# [{"id":1.0,"value":"server1"},{"id":2.0,"value":"server2"},{"id":3.0,"value":"server3"},{"id":4.0,"value":"server4"},{"id":5.0,"value":"server5"}]
```