# Extract json file from R datatable

Tags: json, r, datatable, dt

I have R data.frame like this one:

```
df <- data.frame(RowNames <- c("FirstCol","SecondCol","ThirdCol","FourthCol"),
             FirstCol <- c(0.1,0,0,0.28),
             SecondCol <- c(0,0,0.1,0),
             ThirdCol <- c(0,0,0,0.3),
             FourthCol <- c(0.28,0,0,0.7),
             FifthCol <- c("hi","hello","cus","good bye"))
names(df) <- c("RowNames", "FirstCol", "SecondCol", "ThirdCol", "FourthCol","FifthCol")
```

and I'd like to deploy this data frame into website as a DataTables concept ([link](https://datatables.net/)). So for that purpose I'm using DT package:

```
library(DT)
dt <- datatable(df)
```

But I can see that table only inside of RStudio in it's Viewer. I'd like to use this output table in my website but for that purpose I need json file. Is there any way, how can I extract json file from that DT table and make it useful for my website? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25550711/convert-data-frame-to-json.   jsonlite::toJSON(df)

Comment: or just `htmlwidgets::saveWidget()` to get the whole thing that you can embed