# convert xlsx to json using R

Tags: json, r, xlsx

I first pulled apart the xlsx file, which consisted of multiple sheets.

```
# install.packages("readxl")

library(readxl)
library("rjson")

# read_excel reads
df1 <- read_excel("C:/Users/Adminstrator/Downloads/file.xlsx", sheet = 1)
df2 <- read_excel("C:/Users/Adminstrator/Downloads/file.xlsx", sheet = 2)
df3 <- read_excel("C:/Users/Adminstrator/Downloads/file.xlsx", sheet = 3)
```

The contents of df are as follows.

```
Alabama Hoover 33.40556 -86.81111
Alabama Hoover 33.40565 -86.81314
Alabama Hoover 33.40555 -86.81343
Alabama Dothan 31.22722 -85.40722
Alabama Gadsden 34.01028 -86.01028
Alaska Chugiak 61.38778 -149.48139
...
```

I want to replace this xlsx file with json.

```
{
  "Alabama" : { 
                "Hoover": {
                           "x":[33.40556, 33.40565, 33.40555],
                           "y":[-86.81111, -86.81314, -86.81343]
                          },
                "Dothan": {
                           "x":[31.22722],
                           "y":[-85.40722]
                          },
                  ...
              },
  "Alaska" : {
               "Chugiak" : {
                            "x":[61.38778],
                            "y":[-149.48139]
                           },
               ...
             }
  ...
}
```

How can I change the xlsx file to json?
Please help me.
thanks.

Comment: Your data is not an excel but a data.frame (or some variant of it). You can use `toJSON` function from `rjson` or `jsonlite`. e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25550711/convert-data-frame-to-json

Comment: that's not going to put it into the desired format @RomanLuštrik. The OP wants to have data put into a custom format without doing any work at all. From other q's I don't think R or python is their primary language.

Comment: You can change you data frames to that desired format by programming. 
Grouping/iterating by unique values in the first column then second column and build JSON strings from them. You've not even shown an attempt and where you had issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `split` function of `data.table` is highly useful here.

```
dd <- data.frame(
  state = c("Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alsaka"),
  city = c("Hoover", "Hoover", "Dothan", "Chugiak"),
  x = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
  y = c(5, 6, 7, 8), 
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE
)

library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(dd)
dt_split <- split(dt, by=c("state", "city"), keep.by=FALSE, flatten=FALSE)
```

You get:

```
> dt_split
$Alabama
$Alabama$Hoover
   x y
1: 1 5
2: 2 6

$Alabama$Dothan
   x y
1: 3 7


$Alsaka
$Alsaka$Chugiak
   x y
1: 4 8
```

Now use `jsonlite`:

```
> library(jsonlite)
> toJSON(dt_split, dataframe = "columns", pretty=TRUE)
{
  "Alabama": {
    "Hoover": {
      "x": [1, 2],
      "y": [5, 6]
    },
    "Dothan": {
      "x": [3],
      "y": [7]
    }
  },
  "Alsaka": {
    "Chugiak": {
      "x": [4],
      "y": [8]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate JSON errors (dt_split, dataframe = "columns", pretty = TRUE).
Unused arguments (dataframe = "columns", pretty = TRUE)
This error has occurred. Why this?

Comment: Oh, it's solved. Thank you very much for letting me know !!