# R dataframe into nested list form or json form

Tags: json, r, list, dataframe

I have some troubles in dataframe format.My data is a 3 level nested data like this

```
df = data.frame(index1=c("a","a","b","b","b","c","d","d","d"),index2=c(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1),index3=c(0,0,0,1,2,0,0,1,0),
            value1=c(99,99,88,88,88,77,55,55,55),value2=c(50,50,40,40,40,30,17,17,15),value3=c(55,55,4,4,4,3,1,1,7),
            value4=c(10,15,9,9,9,5,4,4,2),value5=c(10,15,10,10,7,5,2,3,5))
```

I want to transform it into this format

```
{
index1:"a",
value1:99,
index2:[
  {
   value2:50,
   value3:55,
   index3:
   [
     {
     value4:10,
     value5:10
     }
   ]},
  {
   value2:50,
   value3:55,
   index3:
   [
     {
     value4:15,
     value5:15
     }
   ]}

},
{
index1:"b",
value1:88,
index2:[
  {
   value2:40,
   value3:4,
   index3:
   [
     {
     value4:9,
     value5:10
     },
     {
     value4:9,
     value5:10
     },
     {
     value4:9,
     value5:7
     }
   ]}

},
{
index1:"c",
value1:77,
index2:[
  {
   value2:30,
   value3:3,
   index3:
   [
     {
     value4:5,
     value5:5
     }
   ]}

},
{
index1:"d",
value1:55,
index2:[
  {
    value2:17,
    value3:1,
    index3:[
       {
        value4:4,
        value5:2
       },
       {
        value4:4,
        value5:3
       }
     ],
    value2:15,
    value3:7,
    index3:[
      {
       value4:2,
       value5:5
      }
    ]
  }]
}
```

How can I do?? How can I do?? May I use function split and lapply? But I do not know how to use...............................................................................................................................................................

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25550711/convert-data-frame-to-json

Comment: does this get you anywhere?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert data frame to json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25550711/convert-data-frame-to-json)

Comment: Not same.I have 3 level,but your example is just 1 level.

Comment: its not so clear what is the algorithm to come from the table to the json format. why you have in your first sublist `value2:50` and `value3:55` and than as subsublist `value4:10` and `value5:10`?