# Add JSON column to R dataframe

Tags: r, json, dataframe, jsonlite

I have a data frame and want to add an additional column that contains the data per row in JSON format.
In this example:

```
dfr = data.frame(name = c("Andrew", "Mathew", "Dany", "Philip", "John", "Bing", "Monica"), age = c(28, 23, 49, 29, 38, 23, 29))

dfr %>% mutate(Payload = jsonlite::toJSON(dfr))
```

I would like to get

```
Andrew  28   {"name":"Andrew","age":28}
Mathew  23   {"name":"Mathew","age":23}
```

Instead I get per row the JSON string for the complete data frame. 
I tried it with `apply` but I fail to get it to run.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25550711/680068

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try running per each row: split every row, then apply *toJSON* function:

```
dfr$Payload <- sapply(split(dfr, seq(nrow(dfr))), toJSON)

dfr
#     name age                      Payload
# 1 Andrew  28 [{"name":"Andrew","age":28}]
# 2 Mathew  23 [{"name":"Mathew","age":23}]
# 3   Dany  49   [{"name":"Dany","age":49}]
# 4 Philip  29 [{"name":"Philip","age":29}]
# 5   John  38   [{"name":"John","age":38}]
# 6   Bing  23   [{"name":"Bing","age":23}]
# 7 Monica  29 [{"name":"Monica","age":29}]
```

Comment: @StefanG read about purrr to use pipes. Can't find a relevant post at the moment.